# Find circumscribed circle on 3d with 3-points

Tags: algorithm

I have three points A(x0, y0, z0), B(x1, y1, z1), and C(x2, y2, z2) with plane equation.

How to find circumscribed circle in 3d and on this plane??

Comment: Totate the plane normal onto the z-axis with the usual axis rotation matrix `R`. Then find the circumscribed circle's center and radius using the usual 2d method in the x-y plane. Finally apply `R^(-1)` to the center.  You now have the 3d center, radius, and normal vector. This defines the circle in 3d.

Comment: Sorry *** Totate -> Rotate

Comment: @Gene wow thank you. I'll try it.

Comment: @Gene ty. it works perfectly